# Name for a topological space where every closed set contains a closed point

Tags: gn.general-topology, terminology, reference-request

A coauthor and I have stumbled upon a useful topological property -- namely, we are interested in the property that every nonempty closed set contains a closed point.  However, neither of us are topologists, so we don't know whether this exists in the literature yet.  Does it?  If so, what is it called, and where can I find information on it?  If not, I'm happy to just call such a space "pearled" (intuition: the closed sets are the oysters), but I thought I'd ask here before publishing an existing definition under a new name.

By the way, every T$_1$-space is pearled, as is every finite T$_0$-space and every spectral space, but the property of being pearled is independent of the T$_0$-property.  However, I would be interested even in a name for a pearled T$_0$-space.  Is this the same as a T$_0$-space whose lattice of closed sets is atomic?

Comment: Another important example: The topological space underlying a quasi-compact scheme is pearled (and $T_0$). But I'm sure that you already know that :).

Comment: closed point? Are you talking about a Scattered space?

Comment: http://planetmath.org/encyclopedia/ScatteredSet.html (wiki seems to be missing it) 

Comment: a related notion, which I've only heard for schemes though, is that a space is said to be Jacobson if every closed subset is the closure of the subset of its closed points.

Comment: @Brandenburg: I suppose this follows from the fact about spectral spaces.

@Blackmon: I call a point $x$ *closed* if the singleton subset $\{x\}$ that it defines is a closed subset of $X$.  A pearled space need not be scattered.  For example, every T_1 space (hence every Hausdorff space, hence every metric space) is pearled, since every point in such a space is closed.  But a connected metric space with at least two points is never scattered, if I understand the definitions correctly.

Comment: @Berger: That's an interesting property, and it clearly implies mine.  It's a lot stronger, though.  For instance, the Spec of a semilocal ring will never be a Jacobson space unless the ring is zero-dimensional.  I expect the notion of a "Jacobson space" was invented to generalize the idea of a Jacobson ring.

Comment: Any quasicompact $T_0$ space is pearled, since you can just keep intersecting closed sets until you reach a minimal closed set which must be a closed point.

Comment: In answer to your last question, yes, $T_0$+pearled is equivalent to $T_0$+atomic lattice of closed sets. $T_0$ implies that the atomic closed sets are exactly the closed singletons.

Comment: I have heard the term $T_{1/2}$ for a space in which every singleton is either closed or open. This condition implies $T_0+$pearled, so perhaps the latter should be called $T_{1/4}$.

Comment: @de la Vega: Looking in the literature, apparently T_{1/4} already exists.  It means that every point is either closed or an intersection of open sets.  I doubt this is equivalent to T_0 pearled (i.e. to T_0 + atomic lattice of closed -- thanks David), but it certainly isn't implied by it.  For instance, in Spec k[x,y] (k a field; x,y indeterminates) and p=(x), the set {p} isn't closed (since (x,y) is in its closure), and any open set that contains p contains (0) as well.